# Raise warning in Python without interrupting program

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, warnings

I am trying to raise a Warning in Python without making the program crash / stop / interrupt.

I use the following simple function to check if the user passed a non-zero number to it. If so, the program should warn them, but continue as per normal. It should work like the code below, but should use class `Warning()`, `Error()` or `Exception()` instead of printing the warning out manually.

```
def is_zero(i):
   if i != 0:
     print "OK"
   else:
     print "WARNING: the input is 0!"
   return i
```

If I use the code below and pass 0 to the function, the program crashes and the value is never returned. Instead, I want the program to continue normally and just inform the user that he passed 0 to the function.

```
def is_zero(i):
   if i != 0:
     print "OK"
   else:
     raise Warning("the input is 0!")
   return i
```

I want to be able to test that a warning has been thrown testing it by unittest. If I simply print the message out, I am not able to test it with assertRaises in unittest.

Comment: How exactly do you want to notify the user? through email or SMS? cause that can be hooked up but you need to be specific.

Comment: Why don't you just `print` the message?

Comment: @sje397 The point is that I want to be able to test that a warning has been thrown testing it by unittest. If I simply print the message out, I am not able to do that with assertRaises in unittest.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You shouldn't `raise` the warning, you should be using [`warnings`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#module-warnings) module. By raising it you're generating error, rather than warning.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how then do I test that the Warning has been thrown using unittest? I cannot use assertRaises() anymore.

Comment: @Tomas Novotny you can capture stdout and stderr, then check that the strings issued by your warning are found within.

Comment: @Tomas: I never heard of desire to test for warning, but there is available a [`warnings.catch_warnings`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) context manager that will let you do this.

Comment: @SilentGhost If it's in your code, you want to test it, no? https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/warnings.html#warns  (though to be fair that comment is over 10 years old)

Comment: This doesn't explain what to actually do. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3891890/913098) should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 578):

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("Warning...........Message")
```

See the python documentation: [here](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn)

Comment: And `warnings.warn("blabla", DeprecationWarning)` for adding a class to the kind of warning being issued

Answer (score 116):

By default, unlike an exception, a warning doesn't interrupt.

After `import warnings`, it is possible to specify a [Warnings](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#warnings) class when generating a warning. If one is not specified, it is literally [`UserWarning`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#UserWarning) by default.

```
>>> warnings.warn('This is a default warning.')
<string>:1: UserWarning: This is a default warning.
```

To simply use a preexisting class instead, e.g. [`DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#Warning):

```
>>> warnings.warn('This is a particular warning.', DeprecationWarning)
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: This is a particular warning.
```

Creating a custom warning class is similar to creating a custom exception class:

```
>>> class MyCustomWarning(UserWarning):
...     pass
... 
... warnings.warn('This is my custom warning.', MyCustomWarning)

<string>:1: MyCustomWarning: This is my custom warning.
```

For testing, consider [`assertWarns`](https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertWarns) or [`assertWarnsRegex`](https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertWarnsRegex).

---

As an alternative, especially for standalone applications, consider the `logging` module. It can log messages having a level of *debug*, *info*, *warning*, *error*, etc. Log messages having a level of *warning* or higher are by default printed to stderr.

Answer (score 8):

## Just a small demonstration snippet

I was a bit puzzled how to use `warnings.warn`, so I provide here a short demo. Note how print("code running after warning") is executed / not executed after `warnings.warn` / `raise UserWarning`. Also warnings.warn prints the warning message only once.

```py
>>> import warnings
>>> 
>>> warnings.warn("test warning"); print("code running after warning")
<stdin>:1: UserWarning: test warning
code running after warning
>>> 
>>> raise UserWarning('test warning'); print("code running after warning")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UserWarning: test warning
>>> 
>>> warnings.warn("test warning"); print("code running after warning")
code running after warning
```

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the third cases? Why there is different output?

Comment: they are the same. Tge differenec is hence, in the third case, the Warning had been raised already in the past